# Phonegap/Cordova file API. Remove files on uninstall

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a Phonegap/Cordova app that downloads some files and saves them on the device. For this I use the File API.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function (fileSystem) {
        rootPath = fileSystem.root.fullPath;
    }, 
    fail
);
```

On iOS this will set `rootPath` to the private directory of the app, which is good. On Android this will set `rootPath` to the root of the external storage, which is a bit of a problem since these files are not tied to the application and not removed when the App is deleted. As I understand it, the proper way of doing this on Android would be to use `getExternalFilesDir`. How can I get the functionality of `getExternalFilesDir` through Phonegap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd want to request the external files directory via JS.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/com.my.app/files", 
            {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
            function(dirEntry) {
                rootPath = dirEntry.fullPath;
            }, fail);;
    }, 
    fail
);
```

Now you have a path that points to an area that will be cleaned up when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Thank you. That means I have to solve it (slightly) differently for Android and iOS, I Guess? Just out of curiosity, is this because of the support for the old Android (SDK < 8) or is there some other reason for this behaviour?

Comment: When I originally did the File API the decision was to use the external storage to save the files due to the lack of storage on the internal drive. We are actually thinking about moving to the /data/data/{package name} directory to line up better with iOS/BB. My proposal is to create a LocalFileSystem.APP which will eventually become the PERSISTENT constant after every gets used to the change.

Comment: I recently changed from 2.3 to 2.5. Now it seems things are stored in data/data/com.my.app/ instead of /mnt/sdcard/. Does this mean the problem was solved in these versions or do I still need to worry about it?

Comment: Nope, it should still go the external storage directory if the card is mounted.

Comment: @Reason, I defined a helper var and used it for the root offset path [var rootDirOffset = device.platform.toLowerCase() == "android" ? "Android/data/com.my.app/files" : "";]

Comment: @SimonMacDonald any time frame for that proposal to be released?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot track uninstall event. but to delete directory the code is given below.

```
function deleteDirectory(directoyName){
    $scope.fs.root.getDirectory(directoyName,{ create: false, exclusive: false }, function(dirEntry) {
      dirEntry.removeRecursively(function() {
        console.log('Directory Successfully Removed.');
      }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);
  }
```